# Присвоение элементу массива через указатель

Tags: c, указатели, память

Компилируется без ошибок, но при запуске прекращается работа программы.

```
typedef struct _ts_test_buffer{
    int32_t data_buf[MAX_DATA_BUFFER];
    float   filted_buf[MAX_DATA_BUFFER];
}ts_test_buffer;

int main(void)
{
    int32_t i;
    ts_test_buffer * raw_data;

    for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA_BUFFER;i++)
        raw_data->data_buf[i]=0;
}
```

Так ведь можно присвоить или я что-то упустил?
[image]
[image]

Comment: А где выделение памяти под `raw_data`?

Comment: *Присвоение к элементу массива в typedef структуре по ссылке на указатель* - это круто... но говорит о полном непонимании, что такое ссылка (кстати, это в С++, а не в С), что такое указатель и даже typedef, который тут в полной мере ни при чем...

Comment: Если бы я был Компилятором, я бы ругался на отсутствие `return 0;`

Comment: в программе, само собой есть return 0;
Здесь я указал самую суть

Comment: А по поводу непонимания - название "ссылка по указателю" из Кернигана и Ритчи. И это Си.

Comment: @Egor Randomize: С чего бы это вдруг? В функции `main` не обязателен `return 0` и компиляторы это прекрасно знают.

Answer (score 2):

Все логично - raw_data - это просто указатель, в добавок еще и не инициализированный. Поэтому, любые обращения к нему или по полям структуры будут приводить к падениям или непредсказуемым действиям.

Самый простой способ исправить

```
typedef struct _ts_test_buffer{
    int32_t data_buf[MAX_DATA_BUFFER];
    float   filted_buf[MAX_DATA_BUFFER];
}ts_test_buffer;

int main(void)
{
    int32_t i;
    ts_test_buffer raw_data;

    for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA_BUFFER;i++)
        raw_data.data_buf[i]=0;
}
```

или malloc'ом выделить память.

Comment: Действительно, это же просто указатель!
...довольно глупо получилось.
Большое спасибо за разъяснение!

P.S. Но нужен именно указатель, так что помогло выделение памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Только если не забыть память выделить...

```
int main(void)
{
    int32_t i;
    ts_test_buffer * raw_data = malloc(sizeof(ts_test_buffer));

    for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA_BUFFER;i++)
        raw_data->data_buf[i]=0;
}
```

Или хотя бы

```
int main(void)
{
    int32_t i;
    ts_test_buffer t;
    ts_test_buffer * raw_data = &t;

    for(i=0;i<MAX_DATA_BUFFER;i++)
        raw_data->data_buf[i]=0;
}
```

Comment: И освободить. ТС же забудет

Comment: Большое спасибо!
использовал malloc - всё заработало.